# UserControl binding to observablecollection not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I looked around but still can't find a solution...

I made a `UserControl` which is basically a slider but with few custom features.

```
public partial class CustomSlider : UserControl
{
    public CustomSlider()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        CMiXSlider.ApplyTemplate();
        Thumb thumb0 = (CMiXSlider.Template.FindName("PART_Track", CMiXSlider) as Track).Thumb;
        thumb0.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(thumb_MouseEnter);
    }

    private void thumb_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && e.MouseDevice.Captured == null)
        {
            MouseButtonEventArgs args = new MouseButtonEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, MouseButton.Left);
            args.RoutedEvent = MouseLeftButtonDownEvent;
            (sender as Thumb).RaiseEvent(args);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(double), typeof(CustomSlider), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));
    public double Value
    {
        get { return (double)this.GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

The XAML :

```
<UserControl x:Class="CMiX.CustomSlider"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CMiX"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="139.8" d:DesignWidth="546.2">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/CMiX_UserControl;component/RessourceDictionnaries/Brushes/GenericBrushes.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/CMiX_UserControl;component/RessourceDictionnaries/Styles/BaseSliderStyle.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Slider x:Name="CMiXSlider" Style="{StaticResource BaseSliderStyle}" 
            Value="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomSlider}}}" 
            IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" Minimum="0.0" Maximum="1.0"/>
</Grid>
```

Then I use it inside another `UserControl` as so :

```
<CMiX:CustomSlider x:Name="SliderTest" Grid.Row="2" Value="{Binding ChannelsAlpha[0], Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

And I'm trying to bind to this `ObservableCollection` (the same slider will be used 6 times) :

```
private ObservableCollection<double> _ChannelsAlpha = new ObservableCollection<double>(new[] { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 });
    public ObservableCollection<double> ChannelsAlpha
    {
        get { return _ChannelsAlpha; }
        set { _ChannelsAlpha = value; }
    }
```

Problem is, binding is not happening in any way. And what I particularly don't get is if I use this standard slider :

```
<Slider x:Name="Ch0_Alpha" Margin="1" IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" Minimum="0.0" Maximum="1.0" Orientation="Horizontal" Value="{Binding DataContext.ChannelsAlpha[0], ElementName=Ch0_Alpha, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Then it's working as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't bind to anything because you very carefully broke your DataContext:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

Don't do that. To bind to properties of the UserControl itself, use RelativeSource bindings, like... exactly like the one you already used:

```
<Slider 
    x:Name="CMiXSlider" 
    Style="{StaticResource BaseSliderStyle}" 
    Value="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomSlider}}}" 
    IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" 
    Minimum="0.0" 
    Maximum="1.0"
    />
```

I don't see anywhere you're using the DataContext inside the UserControl XAML, so I'd just delete that line in the constructor and go have a beer.

Well, first, for the sake of good form, I'd get rid of the template stuff in the constructor, and move it to OnApplyTemplate:

```
public CustomSlider()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    Thumb thumb0 = (CMiXSlider.Template.FindName("PART_Track", CMiXSlider) as Track).Thumb;
    thumb0.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(thumb_MouseEnter);
}
```

Then beer.

P.S. Here's how to debug bindings:

```
Value="{Binding ChannelsAlpha[0], PresentationTraceSources.TraceMode=High, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Add `PresentationTraceSources.TraceMode=High`, then watch the Output window in VS at runtime. It'll tell you all the steps it takes trying to resolve the binding. What it'll tell you in this case is that it's looking for `ChannelIsAlpha` on that instance of `CMiX:CustomSlider` instead of on the viewmodel. That's your clue that the problem was created by getting rid of the inherited value of `DataContext`. In your constructor, `this.DataContext` was the parent view's viewmodel until you set it to `this` (pop in a breakpoint and see).

This is why some of us cranky old folks have such a burr about not setting `this.DataContext = this;`. First you do it in cases where it's relatively harmless, then you start thinking that's just necessary boilerplate, and here you are. In fact, it's *never* necessary.

Bindings and `DataContext` are painful to get used to because there's this implicit thing going on. I found it very weird at first. Just remember that the assumption is that by default, all bindings will want to bind to the viewmodel, and you should always be able to assume that wherever you are, `DataContext` will be the viewmodel. And never set `DataContext` explicitly.

Binding to anything but the viewmodel is a special case: `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=FooBar}`, `Source={StaticResource WhateverKey}`, `ElementName=FooBarListBox`, `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}`, or whatever.

Comment: In a usercontrol initializecomponent applies the template, so it won't change anything.

Comment: ok everything is working fine, thank you I learn something new. But do you mind telling me just a bit more why this.DataContext = this; broke the datacontext. I thought I was defining it... thanks

Comment: @lecloneur In the containing view, when the bindings on `<CMiX:CustomSlider ...` are resolved, their `Source` is going to be `CMiX:CustomSlider.DataContext` unless you explicitly give them a different source (with `Source=` or `RelativeSource=`). That's where they will look for `ChannelsAlpha`. By default, `DataContext` is *whatever the parent control's DataContext is* -- the viewmodel, in this case.  Leave it alone, and the binding to `ChannelsAlpha` will work. Break it, and it won't. `ChannelsAlpha` is not a property of `CMiX:CustomSlider`. It's a property of the viewmodel.

Comment: @lecloneur You told the binding to look at `CMiX:CustomSlider` to find `ChannelIsAlpha`. Try the `PresentationTraceSources` suggestion with your original code and see what you see in the VS Output pane.